# How to embed Python3 with the standard library

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedding, standard-library

I am attempting to embed Python in an (ultimately multiplatform) C++ app.

It's important that my app contains its own Python implementation (in the same way that blender does), so that it is entirely self-contained. (Else it becomes a configuration minefield).

I have two options:

1. Attempt to embed Python3 *without* the standard library (which I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724057/embed-python3-without-standard-library))
2. **Attempt to embed Python3 *with* the standard library.**

What is required for (2)?

With this information I would be able to balance the merits of each approach against the effort required to set it up.

My embedded Python will be for my own use (rather than any userland scripting) -- mainly control flow / game logic. I will need very little from the standard library -- maybe I can whittle that down to 0 by tunnelling back into C++ whenever necessary -- for example if I need a random number, I can create a C++ routine and access that from Python. I have all of that covered.

However, it is starting to look as though even a minimal installation will have to contain some stdlib component(s), which prompts the question: "If I must include some, maybe it is better to include all!"

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34724057/3005167. (Just mentioning this to prevent accidential flags, like it just almost happened to me :))

Comment: Hm, what's the hiccup? Is there something that isn't working or are you looking for a broad-ish answer for it?

Answer (score 2):

Since this doesn't really have an answer, I will offer this for posterity. I also do not have access to a Mac, so it may be a little different for you than on Linux. Also, the required dependencies must be installed for this to work, but that is usually easy enough to figure out.

Create a working directory

```
mkdir ~/embeddedpython
cd ~/embeddedpython
```

Download the Python source

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz
```

Create an installation directory for Python

```
mkdir ./installation
```

Extract the downloaded source files

```
tar xvf Python-3.6.1.tgz
```

Enter the newly created source directory

```
cd Python-3.6.1
```

Configure Python to install in our installation directory

```
./configure --prefix="/home/<username>/embeddedpython/installation"
```

Make and install Python

```
make && make install
```

Go back to your working directory

```
cd ..
```

Create a new [PYTHONHOME](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) directory where the library will reside

```
mkdir home && mkdir home/lib
```

Copy the Python library to our new home directory

```
cp -r ./installation/lib/python3.6 ./home/lib/
```

Create a new c++ source file (embeddedpython.cpp) with the following code taken from the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding), with the exception of the `setenv` function call.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setenv("PYTHONHOME", "./home", 1);

    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run

```
g++ embeddedpython.cpp -I ./installation/include/python3.6m/ ./installation/lib/libpython3.6m.a  -lpthread -ldl -lutil
./a.out

> Today is Fri Apr 14 16:06:54 2017
```

From here on it is standard embedded python as usual. With this method, the "home" directory must be included in your deployment, and the environment variable `PYTHONHOME` must be set to point to it before any python related code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

### You are looking for [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/)!

It's a **C++ library** which enables *seamless interoperability* between C++ and the Python programming language and in my opinion this should suffice your need, unless you are trying to achieve something else.

It also has a mechanism for embedding the python interpreter into C++ code and one can refer to [this link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/html/reference/embedding.html) (URL isn't release specific) to delve into the possibilities.

P.S. I believe less in reinventing the wheel and more into the re-usability.

Comment: This answer is very vague. You should include some kind of (further) explanation or concrete implementation for the task the OP is trying to approach.

Comment: Moreover, subtle personal comments or opinions are well-received if they are accompanied with a high-quality explanation, but not if they virtually substitute it all.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have already double check how to Embedding Python in Another Application ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) you will see something which cover embedding python2 but will be true for python3 also in my opinion)

There is different types of embedding:

- Very High Level Embedding
- Beyond Very High Level Embedding
- Pure Embedding
- Embedding Python in C++

As your question is relative to "Embedding Python in C++" you may read this:

> It is also possible to embed Python in a C++ program; **precisely how
>   this is done will depend on the details of the C++ system used**; in
>   general you will need to write the main program in C++, and use the
>   C++ compiler to compile and link your program. There is no need to
>   recompile Python itself using C++.

As one hand you said "*(ultimately multiplatform) C++ app*", and in the other hand you have "*precisely how this is done will depend on the details of the C++ system used*", so may you explain more details of the C++ system used ?

You may also find some tips [here](https://skebanga.github.io/embedded-python-pybind11/) relative to the use of [pybind11 module](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) or another [old page](http://blog.dmaggot.org/2009/12/embed-python-and-import-modules-in-cc/) which treat about how to Embed Python and Import Modules in C/C++ (python2.6 but I hope you may found inspiration with)

To conclude:

> You'll obviously need development packages for Python in order to have
>   the Python include directory